# JAVA MQ SSL\TLS connection with IBM MQ V8 jars not working

Tags: java, ssl, jms, ibm-mq

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

  // Config
  cf.setHostName("XXXXXXX");
  cf.setPort(1414);
  cf.setTransportType(1);
  cf.setQueueManager("XXXXXXXX");
  cf.setChannel("XXXXXXXX");
  cf.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA");

// SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
// cf.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);

  MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
  MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///QUEUE.NAME");
  MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
  MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);      

  long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
  JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage("SimplePTP "+ uniqueNumber);     
  message.setJMSExpiration(15l);
  // Start the connection
  connection.start();

  sender.send(message);
  System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

  JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
  System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);
```

Above code does not work, I get below error 
`com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2059' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE')`.

Just to clarify, I have given proper keystore,truststore in VM arguments. but somehow keystore does not get picked up while SSL handshake.

But if I add below two lines in the code...

```
  SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
  cf.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
```

...it works!!!! Looks like somehow version 8 jar is not able to create default SSLSocketFactory.

Any idea? Version 7.5 jars works without these 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a configuration problem, likely due to bad `CLASSPATH` but possibly other config issues.

The quickest thing to do is validate that your setup conforms to IBM's specifications as described in Installation and configuration of *[IBM MQ classes for Java](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030580_.htm)* and in particular, the section on *[Environment variables relevant to IBM MQ classes for Java](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030610_.htm)*.  Check that no old libraries are in the directories specified by the `CLASSPATH`.

Also, have a look at the `setjmsenv` scripts in the `java/bin` directory.  These are meant to be sourced prior to running a JMS program.  Even though you are using MQ Java classes, you can either use these in your run script or look through them to understand what they do and the settings on which the classes depend.

I am assuming that you have not done this level of validation because the original question does not mention having performed any of the standard troubleshooting.  What it does mention is having previously used a different version of the jar files and if all that was done was to swap the new jars into the old config then odd behavior is the expected result.  If you *have* performed some troubleshooting and validated your setup, please update your question with the relevant details.

If the `CLASSPATH` and other config elements are sanity-checked and this still persists, see if it happens with the IVT program as described in *[Verifying your IBM MQ classes for Java installation with the sample application](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030690_.htm)*.  Since the IVT program is known-good code its behavior will help determine whether the issue is something in MQ or something in your setup.